# Can I draw a bar chart using only HTML div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can any please suggest how to draw a bar chart using only HTML DIV with all features like legends, animation(each bar should animate from 0(Y axis value 0), etc.

Comment: What have you done to accomplish this so far? Please post your code.

Comment: What specifically are you struggling with? Simply asking people to code it for you is not really appropriate

Comment: Is there a reason for the requirement of only using a div? Using inline SVG, which is supported on nearly every browser in use today except IE8, would likely be a very good fit for this task.

Comment: Need some idea or suggestion(links) to start. Yes We can do it SVG or canvas, just wanted to know for my curiosity whether we can do the same using only DIV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [d3 introductory tutorials](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials). The second tutorial shows how to make bar charts using divs. You could create static barcharts with some html and css but since your question is tagged with javascript this might be a good place to start.

The same or better can be achieved by applying the same principles to SVG.

Good luck!